# Volver al inicio del Main

Tags: c#

Este es mi main que ya incluye una bandera para salir del programa (seguir):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

  string[] nombre;
  int opcion, tope = 0, cantidad;
  bool seguir = true;



  Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad: ");

  cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  int[] vector = new int[cantidad];
  nombre = new string[cantidad];
  int[, ] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];


  while (seguir) {

   Console.WriteLine("\t\t1-Reset");
   Console.WriteLine("\t\t2-Salir");

   opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   switch (opcion) {
    case1:


    string reset = Console.ReadLine();

    if (reset == "SI") {
     //CODIGO

    }
    Console.ReadLine();


    break;

    case2;
    seguir = false;
    break;
```

Lo que busco es que cuando escriba si, vuelva al inicio a pedir cantidad y empiece de 0 (resetear la matriz), y si es no, vuelva al menu normal, es necesario que sea con un while o bandera, no puedo usar un goto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61376/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-eleaefe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo mejor que podes hacer es agregar un bandera `primeravez = true`, y mover toda la parte de dimensionamiento de los vectores dentro del while, de esta forma:

```
while (seguir) 
{
    if (primeravez == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad: ");
        cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        vector = new int[cantidad];
        nombre = new string[cantidad];
        matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];
        primeravez = false;
    } 
    ...
    if (reset == "SI") {
        //CODIGO
        primeravez = true;
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias!

Comment: como estas? me añadis a un chat? tengo una consulta

Answer (score 2):

Basta hacer un while anidado

```
using System; 
public class TuClase
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] nombre;

        int opcion;
        int cantidad;
        int tope;

        int[] vector;
        int[,] matriz;

        int estado = 0;

        do {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad: ");
            cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            nombre = new string[cantidad];
            vector = new int[cantidad];
            matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];

            do {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t1-Reset");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t2-Salir");

                opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                estado = SEGUIR;

                switch (opcion) {
                case REINICIAR:
                    Console.WriteLine("Esta seguro que desea reiniciar las jugadas? [S/N]");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "S")
                        estado = REINICIAR;
                    break;
                case SALIR:
                    estado = SALIR;
                    break;
                }
            } while(estado == SEGUIR);

        } while(estado == REINICIAR);
    }

    private const int REINICIAR = 1;
    private const int SALIR = 2;
    private const int SEGUIR = 3;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No es necesario usar `goto`, de hecho, su uso esta desaconsejado por expertos en el tema.

Podrias simplemente reiniciar la funcion `Main()`, de esta manera:

```
if (reset == "SI")
{
    Main(args);
}
```

Lo que hara este fragmento sera llamar la funcion `Main()` de una manera recursiva.

Al usar la recursividad, "la funcion se llama a ella misma", lo que permitira que todas las variables y declaraciones vuelvan a su estado original.

Comment: no me parece que llamar recursivamente main sea una buena solucion. Soluciona el problema, pero crea otros (como cargar la memoria con un monton de cosas, que no sepa el comportamiento esperado a la salida de la misma).

Comment: @ivan-botero gracias, pero necesito hacerlo con una bandera como consigna

Comment: @eleaefe Necesitas volver al inicio del bucle?

Comment: @ivan-botero, necesito ir al inicio del programa cuando me pide la cantidad de jugadores